# Android gradle compilation fails using java 1.8, jack and lambda

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use java 8 in my projects, but an unknown problem occurs when I use lambda expression.

**Exception:**
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':SLL:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

**Caused by:** org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed;

There is not wrong in my project when I run without lambda:

This code below work Perfectly

```
act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Alert dialog here
    }
});
```

But using lambda fails and throws the exception above

```
act.runOnUiThread(()->{
    // Alert dialog here
});
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8 // or JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
}
```

I have no idea what's happening.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly Hey John, newest 2.2.3, thank u

Comment: Are you running Android Studio using Java 8?

Comment: Yes John, I work with java 8 in android studio (jdk1.8.0_92)

Comment: Sorry, probably obvious questions :)  Strange,  using same settings here and working

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly What are values you use in compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion?

Comment: compileSdkVersion 25, targetSdkVersion 25,  buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

Comment: have you try to update all your build/platform tools, invalidate cache and restart studio, gradle clean ?

Comment: @OrestSavchak see my answer below

Comment: i thought it is applciation as you posted application build.gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a temporary solution, the problem occurs only when we use lambda in libraries, becouse its not support jack, jack is supported only in the main app, we are waitting android allows libs to enable jack, but before that, we can add the code below to the build.gradle libraries file.

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xbootclasspath/a:" + System.properties.get("java.home") + "/lib/rt.jar"
    }
}
```

That solution works only with the our own interfaces, others like Runnable causes compilation error.